# Allow users to add markers based on name of places instead of coordinates and then allow then to filter

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a group of 10 volunteers who will distribute flyers in different areas. I want to make a web page where they can login and then add their markers by searching for the place instead of coordinates (if believe its done through Geocoding??). Then once the user is logged in I want them to filter the markers by "My markers" and "All markers" category.

So 2 things. How to make the user search using name instead of coordinates and add the marker. And second, how to filter the markers.

Thanks
Karan

Answer (score 0):

Have you read

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes

? Then keep track of users' markers with an object referencing a Marker array, such as `user['bob'] = [marker 1, marker 2, etc.]` and switch on and off based on these user names.

When you run into a specific problem come back here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you should use [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get the user to the exact spot he wants.Then you can add the user markers in your database together with the userid so you can filter them by mymarkers.